# ActionScript 3. Drag and drop game going wrong

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop, collision-detection, target

I have flash game written in *ActionScript 3*, here are 4 items which should be dragged to specific fields, It's working correctly when dragging item to any fields (If correct field - item get field's `x`, `y` position and if field is wrong - item returns to his fixed position).

It's going wrong when I'm trying to drop item on other item (for example trying to drag and drop `Item1` on `Item2`), they change positions. If I drag `Item1` and It not *hitTestObject* correct field It should get back to `Items1`'s position, but It going to `Item2` `x`, `y` position and `Item2` to Item1 `x`, `y` position.

I'm using following code:

```
private function getPosition(target:Object):void 
{
    xPos = target.x;
    yPos = target.y;
}
private function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    getPosition(e.target);
    e.target.startDrag();
    trace("Started drag");
}
private function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.target.hitTestObject(e.currentTarget.parent[field])) {
        e.target.x = (e.currentTarget.parent[field]).x;
        e.target.y = (e.currentTarget.parent[field]).y;
    } else {
        e.target.x = xPos; //here is part where item get's back to his position
        e.target.y = yPos; //seems that here is problem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a depth problem ( index position ) of your items, because, for example, when you drag an item with a depth 1 over another one with index 5, the target of your `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` event will be the second object and not the first, so I think that you can avoid that by setting the index of your current item as the highest in your items container like this :

```
function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void {

    var container:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(e.target.parent);
        container.setChildIndex(DisplayObject(e.target), container.numChildren - 1);

    // other instructions

}
```

**EDIT :**

To avoid your second problem ( positioning the target of `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` event at (0, 0) or under the last dragged object ), you can use a boolean var to indicate if you are dragging an item or not :

```
var is_dragging:Boolean = false;

function dragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    is_dragging = true;

    // other instructions
}
function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{   
    if(!is_dragging) return;

    // other instructions

    is_dragging = false;    
}
```

The boolean var is just a manner, you can also initialize your `xPos` and `yPos`, ...

**Note :** To reproduce the problem, you can just click anywhere on your stage and release your mouse over an item, this item will be positioned at (0, 0) because `xPos` and `yPos` are undefined, but if you have already dragged an other item, the item be positioned at (`xPos`, `yPos`), so under your last dragged item.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you, It helped, but still here is bug like: If I start to clicking and dragging (anywhere) quickly  item1, later item2, later again item1, later item2 and repeating it so on, they all get to 1 position in this example item2 on item1(not changing position like was before, but spawns one on other)

Comment: Upvoted, at evening I will be able to test It, after testing If It will work I'll accept answer and let you know If that worked for me.